# Two Sets of controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am creating a site with two bindings

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default", 
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "DefaultAdmin",
  url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The idea is  I want to have EndUsers to access the normal pages (`/account/login` etc etc ) but have a admin only portion of the site (with a different layout) for admin users.

The question is kinda two fold :-

1. In terms of controllers it looks like MVC just looks in the Controllers folder, is there a way to seperate out AdminControllers and Regular controllers to keep things organised?
2. I would like to have a separate "master view" appear for the admin than the regular, currently I'm just using `_layout.cshtml` from `_start.cshtml` but I'd like to be able to use `_layout.cshtml` and `_adminLayout.cshtml` without prefixing every view with the name of the view (if not then I can live with this one easily enough).

Any help would be apprechited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place controllers anywhere in the assembly as long as they are derived from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class they will be identified by the routing logic.

You could look at "Areas" in MVC to help out with your specific need.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [`Areas`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/aspnet-mvc-2-areas) in MVC is what you are looking for.